# Local Gem assets not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I've forked a gem, and in trying to change it, decided to change the the gemfile from my git repository (which had been updating fine):

```
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/Asherlc/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails.git'
```

to the local directory (just the cloned git repository):

```
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', :path => '/Users/ashercohen/Documents/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
```

Upon running either `bundle update` or `bundle install`, it shows the correct version number (updated since switching gem sources) in the readout. However, none of the files in the `/vendor/assets`path seem to be getting updated in my Rails app. Is there some kind of caching thing I need to clear out?

I don't have a `/vendor/cache` file in my Rails app, and I'm confident that since the gem version is updating correctly in the bundler readout that the path is correct.

Is there some step I'm missing here?

Comment: I suspect you're missing a "depend_on" directive... I know this probably sounds weird, but does it work if you add a random comment into your application.js and application.css.scss files?

Comment: Ach, thank you! The code actually was updating, as your comment suggestion revealed. For some reason, Chrome is caching it with a vengeance, so the changes weren't showing up in the console.

Comment: I had a weird issue once where my local gem wasn't updating. Resolved it by removing the gem from my gemfile, running `bundle install`, adding it back and running `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Chrome was just aggressively caching the JS.